# Cannot POST data to server through angularjs's $http module

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax, angularjs-http

I am coding using angular ajax. The client side code is:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '----/test.php',
    data: ({'txtDeviceID': 12345678}),
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/text'
    }
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log(response)
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log(response)
});
```

The server side code is:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With,Content-Type, Accept");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');
echo $_POST['txtDeviceID'];
```

Why can't I get the `texDeviceId`? Thank you for your time!

Comment: try `data: {'txtDeviceID':12345678}` (i.e. without the brackets) and `'Content-type': 'application/json'`

Comment: You might wanna send the data back using `json_encode`

Comment: @ADyson i did it still showing error

Comment: @Debojyoti what error do you get?

Comment: @gevorg no value is being sent through the server

Comment: is it the same if you replace `echo $_POST['txtDeviceID'];
` with `echo "SOME ODD STRING";`?

Comment: Ok, got your problem, you need to use `'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your problem

Your problem is, because you send JSON data to PHP file, but PHP expects it to be in form param format:

- your client code sends `{'txtDeviceID': 12345678}`
- but server code expects `txtDeviceID=12345678`

To solve this you have two options, changing your client code to send data in form param format or changing your server code to expect data in JSON format.

### changing your your client code

Look for `response.data` and change request's `content-type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, additionally you should transform your data to form format using [`$httpParamSerializer`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/docs/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer).

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '----/test.php',       
    data: $httpParamSerializer({ 'txtDeviceID': 12345678 }),  
    // or data: "txtDeviceID=12345678",
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log(response.data)
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log(response)
});
```

For more info read [$http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

> The response object has these properties:
>
> - `data` – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the
>     transform functions.
> - `status` – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
> - `headers` – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
> - `config` – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate
>     the request.
> - `statusText` – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

### or changing your server code.

To get raw submitted data you need to use `file_get_contents('php://input')`

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With,Content-Type, Accept");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');

$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
echo $_POST['txtDeviceID'];
```

Comment: But i can see in console.log(response) that the data property has empty value

Comment: @Debojyoti got it, your problem is in headers, because you don't set proper header for content type, use this `'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

Comment: @Debojyoti additionally you need to convert submitted data to form format using `$httpParamSerializer`.

Comment: @Debojyoti there is an alternative to that where you can just change your server code.

Answer (score 2):

set 'Content-type': 'application/json'

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '----/test.php',
    data: {"txtDeviceID":12345678},
    headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
}
  }).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response)
    }, function (response) {
      console.log(response)
    });
```

modify your php file like this

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With,Content-Type, Accept");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');


$jsonstring = file_get_contents ( 'php://input' );
$arr = json_decode($jsonstring,true);
echo $arr["txtDeviceID"];
```

Answer (score 2):

In your PHP, change `echo $_POST['txtDeviceID'];` to `echo json_encode($_POST['txtDeviceID']);`

and in your controller Make sure that `data` is on *object*.

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '----/test.php',
    data: {'txtDeviceID':12345678}
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // look specifically for "txtDeviceID"
    console.log(response.data.txtDeviceID)
    }, function errorCallback(error) {
      console.log(error)
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use $http interceptor like the one below, it work for me

```
(function(){
  angular.module('xxxxxxx').factory('sessionInjector', function() {  
      var sessionInjector = {
          request: function(config) {

              config.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem('token');

              if(config.method == 'POST') {
                if(config.data) {
                  config.data = $.param(config.data); //jQuery magic but php likes
                }
              }

              return config;
          },
          response: function(res) {
              console.log(res);
                return res;
          }
      };
      return sessionInjector;
  });
}());
```